# Throwing exceptions in a Java Library Best Practice

Tags: java, jar, exception

I am developing an JAR library for database access. I first caught all the exceptions that are found in try blocks and handled them. 
But later, I thought it would be better since its a library to throw the exception to the end-programmer to catch it and do the handling.

What is the best practice regarding handling exceptions in JAR files?

The following is a sample code from my JAR, and as you can see there are many exceptions thrown. Is that a good practice or is there a way to do this better? (Like defining a new custom exception; if so, how is it done?)
Any help regarding this is much appreciated.

```
 public static NConnection getNConnection(String path) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {

    NConfigurations conf = new NConfigurations();
    conf.setConfigurationLoc(path);
    String dbPath = conf.getDatabasePath();
    return createConnection(dbPath);
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "handling exceptions in JAR files"?..

Comment: Defining a custom exception is easy: `public class CustomException extends Exception{}`

Comment: I am coding a java library for db access, and would like to know whether its best to throw the exceptions in method signatures or just handle the exception in try-catch blocks.

Comment: You should understand de difference between checked exception and runtime exception first. if path is provided by the library user, he/she needs to catch the exception when the file does not exists in the path. Also if file is not in expected format. That is you should throw all the errors in your case. That's my opinion...

Comment: Thank you, so as per your suggestion since all three exceptions thrown here are Checked, I'll have to throw them and ask the end-programmer to handle.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy answer to that and the community is somehow undecided about what is actually best practice. In a nutshell you can **use checked exceptions** if you want to force the caller to handle the case that something went wrong / give him a chance to recover from this exceptional state. **Use runtime exceptions** for any other cases like programming errors like violating contracts or such.

In my opinion it is best practice for any library to **extend its own exception class**, even if it does nothing more than wrapping the original exception. This way - as a client - I can read the stacktrace and easily spot in which part of my code something went wrong. E.g. if there is a DBFrameworkException it's much more clear than the common NullPointerException.

Also see [Bloch's Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) item 58 for some good explanation on this topic.

Comment: All three exceptions thrown in the sample code are checked. Is it ok to throw multiple exceptions for the end-programmer to handle ? or is it frowned upon in good design principles.

Comment: I'd not recommend it as it will blow up the size of the caller's code a lot. It's not really bad design, just cumbersome to use as a client.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, So I would go with wrapping up the three exceptions in maybe a  "DBFrameworkException " and throw it so the user will know where and what went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it both ways: you can throw the original exceptions or you can nest them in your own custom exception. It is a design decision.

Usually it makes sense to throw exceptions that are related logically to the code functionality. For ex. if you do I/O operations, you would expect an IOException since this is a natural problem that may arise from the i/o operation.

In your case: it depends what is the NConnection abstraction all about. Maybe it doesn't make sense to expose the IOException if that's implementation specific. You can create your own application-specific exception and wrap the io exception:

```
try {
   // code that throws i/o exception 
} catch (IOException ioe) {
   throw new NException("Something went wrong", ioe);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should catch all underlying exceptions such as the ones you have in the method signature (e.g. IOException) and then if needed you throw your own custom exception with the message and type you feel is appropriate.

The reason for this has to do with good programming practices where you may want to substitute a library you were previously using (e.g. a jdbc driver) with something else. you dont want user code to break when importing your new version on a lets say MySQL duplicate key error when instead you could be using a generic duplicate key exception.

Answer (score 1):

I think **throwing** is a better way, because one who using the jar can handle those exceptions in java classes.Just like DriverManage.getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException.